# Multiple annotations found this line

Tags: jsp

```
<a href="http://pravysoft.eu5org/sms.php?<%=id%>"></a>;
```

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- Syntax error on token "<", delete 
   this token
- Syntax error on token "<", delete 
   this token

In the above line i am getting like this error please help me thanks in advance

```
<% String username="9566193155"; 
String password="232323";
String to="9566193155"; 
String msg="TEST"; 
<a href="pravysoft.eu5org/sms.php?<%=id%>"></a>;; 
/* sendsms.init(); 
sendsms.server = 192.168.1.4; 
sendsms.user = 9566193155; 
sendsms.password = 232323; 
sendsms.phonenumber = +9566193155?; 
sendsms.text = This is a test message; 
sendsms.send(); */ %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is in between `<%` and `%>` in a JSP must be valid Java code.

`<a href="pravysoft.eu5org/sms.php?<%=id%>"></a>;;` is not valid Java code. That's why you get the error message.

You could replace that line with

```
%>
<a href="pravysoft.eu5org/sms.php?<%=id%>"></a>
<%
```

however, I'm not sure that this will solve your problem. The whole snippet that you post is not very clear: You seem to be implementing the sending of an SMS in a JSP, but the link you mention points to a PHP file utilizing a parameter (`id`) that is undeclared - at least in the snippet posted here.

Well, find the exact answer to your question above. Just don't expect that then everything works, I suspect that there are a other problems elsewhere.

Comment: hi to every one i have one doubt in mysql table i have lots of rows are their i want select all rows at a time and i need to update one rows only at a time in jsp code please anyone help me for this solution

Comment: ...but that's got nothing to do with this question or answer. Just ask a separate question.

Comment: how to ask separate question sir tell me procedure i dont know because i am new for this sit thank you

Comment: The same way you asked your first question. Top right on every page is a link "Ask question". You might want to read the content of the "help" link in the top toolbar before. Also, if the answer here helped your problem, there's a checkmark that you can click to accept - otherwise you should comment on why it doesn't

Comment: thank you sir but its shwing your question is maximum limit

Comment: sir i am trying to build one small academic project i need your help can i communicate with you dicectly your personal account via email?           Olaf Kock sir

Comment: Let's go one by one and finish the first question (this one). It seems that you're running into the [new user limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited) which is - together with all its reasons - well laid out. Everything has been said there. While I'm happy to provide answers _here_, personal email support is out of the game. Your cooperation with each individual question is appreciated. So please give a signal as to the status of this answer. And please read through the help section as indicated above. Gain reputation and the question limit will be lifted automatically